# Installing Cassandra in EMR cluster, getting "Connection timed out"

Tags: cassandra

```
$ wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/cassandra/4.0.8/apache-cassandra-4.0.8-bin.tar.gz

--2023-02-19 04:04:57--  
https://dlcdn.apache.org/cassandra/4.0.8/apache-cassandra-4.0.8-bin.tar.gz
Resolving dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)... 151.101.2.132, 2a04:4e42::644
Connecting to dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)|151.101.2.132|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)|2a04:4e42::644|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask]  and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the host doesn't have access to the Cassandra tarball CDN mirror.

Try getting a copy of the C* 4.0.8 tarball from the Apache Archives:

```
$ curl -OL http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/4.0.8/apache-cassandra-4.0.8-bin.tar.gz
```

Just note that there's a good chance this won't work either since it appears your host doesn't have internet access. If so, you might have to download the tarball to your laptop/desktop then upload it (via FTP, SCP, etc) to your server. Cheers!